# Windows Browser ignoring route table

Tags: windows, browser, proxy, routes

I have 2 NICs in my machine, both have access to the internet and different local subnets, but:

NIC #8 (10.0.0.0/24) is supposed to handle all internet traffic

NIC #12 (172.23.0.0/16) is supposed to handle all local traffic

IPv6 is disabled for both NICs.

"route show" revealed that there were 2 routes to 0.0.0.0, one via #8, one via #12, so I removed the one via #12.
tracerts now correctly use NIC #8 to reach destinations outside my local network.
Browsers however still use the route via NIC #12 to reach the internet. I checked for proxies (netsh winhttp show proxy), I made sure the adapter metrics are set to prefer NIC #8, I tried adding a permanent static route and rebootet, but no luck.

I also tried removing all routes to locations outside our local network. tracerts now return an error as they cannot find a route anymore, like expeteced. With my browser however I'm still able to access the internet.

This is my current routing table, which delivers the correct behaviour using tracert:

```
IPv4-Routentabelle
===========================================================================
Aktive Routen:
     Netzwerkziel    Netzwerkmaske          Gateway    Schnittstelle Metrik
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        10.0.0.20      2
         10.0.0.0    255.255.255.0   Auf Verbindung         10.0.0.20    257
        10.0.0.20  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung         10.0.0.20    257
       10.0.0.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung         10.0.0.20    257
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    306
       172.23.0.0      255.255.0.0   Auf Verbindung      172.23.70.25    356
     172.23.70.25  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung      172.23.70.25    356
   172.23.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung      172.23.70.25    356
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung      172.23.70.25    356
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung         10.0.0.20    257
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung      172.23.70.25    356
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung         10.0.0.20    257
===========================================================================
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I'll go ahead and bump this one.

Problem still not solved: Tracert uses routes defined in my Routing table, but Browsers and other Software still seem to be ignoring the Routing table.

Answer (score 0):

I will tell you what I know that may help.
First open Network and Sharing Center from Control panel,
Click Change adapter settings, press alt-n and select advanced settings,
the preffered adapter is at the top.

Windows 7 routing will try routes in the routing table but has a "feature" called dead gateway detect, it will ignore the route table if the gateway for the route does not respond. This can cause packets destined for LAN adapter to go to WAN adapter.

I was unable to prevent this behaviour, while trying to create bogon routes. EnableDeadGWDetect=0 had no effect. The only way I suceeded to create a bogon route on Win 7 was to create a route to a machine that is alive but does not have routing enabled. I suspect this "feature" is why your packets end up where you do not expect them.